# JSTL, can not populate combo box

Tags: java, combobox, jstl

I have issue populating a combo box.

I use following code in my JSP file:

```
<select style="width: 143px" name="selectedUser">
                            <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}">
                                <option value='<c:out value="${user.id}"/>'>
                                    <c:out value="${user.name}" />
                                </option>
                            </c:forEach>
                    </select>
```

but when I run the web application, my combo box is empty.

It works fine when I use scriptlet:

```
<select style="width: 143px" name="selectedUser">
                            <%
                                for (Korisnik user : userList) {
                                    String userValue = user.getSurname() + " " + user.getName();
                                    out.write("<option value='" + user.getId() + "'>"
                                            + userValue + "</option>");
                                }
                            %>
                    </select>
```

Also, I want combobox to be populated with a String that is surname + name, as shown in scriptlet. Why doesn't my JSPL code work, and how could I populate it with surname and name in JSTL.

I appreciate any assistance, thank you

EDIT

```
package hr.tvz.web.aplikacije.domain;
```

Class Korisnik:

```
package hr.tvz.web.aplikacije.domain;

public class Korisnik {
private int identifikator;
private String korisnickoIme;
private String ime;
private String prezime;

public Korisnik(int identifikator, String korisnickoIme, String ime,
        String prezime) {
    super();
    this.identifikator = identifikator;
    this.korisnickoIme = korisnickoIme;
    this.ime = ime;
    this.prezime = prezime;
}

public int getIdentifikator() {
    return identifikator;
}

public String getKorisnickoIme() {
    return korisnickoIme;
}

public String getIme() {
    return ime;
}

public String getPrezime() {
    return prezime;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for Class Korisnik ?

Comment: I've edited the question, it contains the code you asked for

Comment: Whatever attributes you are looking for in JSTL doesn't exist on the class. Can you paste your actual JSTL code?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `<c:out>`. Try to use this:

```
<select style="width: 143px" name="selectedUser">
     <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}" >
           <option value="${user.id}" />
                  ${user.surname} ${user.name}
           </option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```

I tested something similar to this in my project and it worked fine for me. Hope that can help you too.

Answer (score 0):

I am grateful for all the help.
I found where the problem was, and I kinda feel silly now. I've been using scriptlet to get attribute from servlet, after I replaced the scriptlet with equivalent JSTL code, it worked just as it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select style="width: 143px" name="selectedUser">
  <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList.rows}">
    <option value='<c:out value="${user.id}"/>'>
      <c:out value="${user.name}" />
    </option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Now,you can try it.